# Create array names based on variable value

Tags: php, arrays

Basically, what I want is like this [creating variable names from an array list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584996/creating-variable-names-from-an-array-list)

But it's the other way around, instead of creating normal variables, I want to create arrays from the variable values

Comment: What do you mean by "Create array names"? If that's not relevant, couldn't you just make an array containing the variables like you create any other array?

Comment: please elaborate more what u exact want: write your desired array and input array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make an array which maps variable names to their values, use `compact()`, passing variable names as strings:

```
$one = 1;
$two = 2;

$variables = compact('one', 'two'); // Array ( [one] => 1, [two] => 2 )
```

If all you want is an array containing the values of your variables, just make a normal array using `array()` and toss your variables in:

```
$one = 1;
$two = 2;

$variables = array($one, $two); // Array ( [0] => 1, [1] => 2 )
```

Comment: beat to me :), but does OP really want this??