# Variables into array - $array[$var_name] = $var;

Tags: php, arrays, variables, names

I was wondering whether something like this is possible:

```
$var1 = 1; $var2 = 2;
function varsToArray($param1, $param2...);
```

and it returns array like this

```
array([var1] => 1, [var2] => 2).
```

Simply saying, I'd like arrays keys to be same as variable names. The problem is I don't know how to get variable name as string to put it as key(if possible of course...).

Comment: Well, since that's not valid PHP syntax it's obviously not possible to ascertain what you mean by it. Describe your goal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create array names based on variable value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6000147/create-array-names-based-on-variable-value) ... please use the search before you ask a question.

Comment: @Felix Kling, nah, no exactly the same problem it seems

Comment: Then you did not describe your problem properly... the accepted answer puts the **parameter** names in the array, not the **variable** names, and I wonder why one would use reflection in this case.

Comment: Nope, I meant varaibles. Noticed after a while that Yoshi's solutions puts parameters names as keys, not varaibles names. Sry, my fault. The example i gave is bad, I'll change it

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the [`compact` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) methinks.

Comment: compact works when you pass variables names as strings so compact("var1", "var2"); I wish to pass just as compact($var1, $var2). In this case @Yoshi's solution works fine:D

Comment: @f1ames: It works because the function's parameters are called `$var1` and `$var2`. If you call `foo($bar, $baz)`, the output will still contain `var1`, `var2`. I think passing the variable names as string is the only useful solution.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in PHP function [`compact()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) does this.

BTW: I'm going to go ahead and assume that instead of:

```
function $varsToArray($var1, $var2...);
```

you actually meant:

```
function varsToArray($var1, $var2...);
```

Notice the dollar sign has been removed.